# Find absolute paths to folder contents

Tags: macos, applescript, filepath

Another newbie applescript question. I'm trying to get absolute paths to all of the folders and files inside of a folder upon opening it. I'd like to write something like

```
on opening folder this_folder
   tell application "Finder"
      set everyPath to POSIX path of every item in entire contents of this_folder
   end tell

   repeat with n from 1 to count of everyPath
      display dialog item n of everyPath
   end repeat
end opening folder
```

But this s***s a brick so right now I have this even uglier mess.

```
on opening folder this_folder
   tell application "Finder"
      set everyName to name of every item in entire contents of this_folder
      set everyPath to {}
      repeat with n from 1 to count of everyName
         set end of everyPath to POSIX path of item n of everyName
      end repeat
   end tell

   repeat with n from 1 to count of everyPath
      display dialog item n of everyPath
   end repeat
end opening folder
```

Which diplays dialogs like '/file.ext' when I'm looking for something more like 'User/username/documents/folder/file.ext' and 'User/username/documents/folder/subfolder/file2.ext'.

Judging by my tendency to miss the obvious in the past, I'm assuming there's an easy way to get full path names that I'm just oblivious to, and I would appreciate any help in sorting it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you're trying. Normally you can just add the folder path to a name to get the full path. However you're also getting names of files in sub folders, so that won't work because you don't know the subfolder paths. As such getting names from the Finder won't help you. A faster method than the Finder for something like this may be to use the unix program "find".

```
set this_folder to path to desktop

-- we have to remove the trailing / from the folder path so the
-- returned paths from the find command are correct
set posix_folder to text 1 thru -2 of (POSIX path of this_folder)

-- use find to quickly find the items in this_folder
-- also filter out invisible files and files in invisible folders
-- also filter files inside of package files like ".app" files
set theItems to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & quoted form of posix_folder & " -name \"*.*\" ! -path \"*/.*\" ! -path \"*.app/*\" ! -path \"*.scptd/*\" ! -path \"*.rtfd/*\" ! -path \"*.xcodeproj/*\"")
```

And if the find command isn't appropriate then you could use the mdfind command (e.g.. spotlight through the command line) in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. The only issue is that I also need to return the path to subdirectories as well, not just the files in them. Is there a way to do this using unix?